# how to use woocommerce for variable with measurment product

Tags: wordpress

I want to make my Wordpress site totally Ecommerce unless the user logs in with Facebook. So, the users have to login via Facebook to enter/view the site.

It is a demo site so I am not worried about "but what if the user doesn't have a Facebook account".

I have searched for Facebook plugins but my results all seemed to focus on posting to Facebook.

Is this possible via a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Measurement Price Calculator extension for WooCommerce allows you to add and configure a calculator to your products that are sold in quantities based on their dimensions, square footage, volume, or weight. This allows you to easily sell products which have a known measurement per item. For instance, let’s say you have tile that’s sold for $2.09 per square foot, and you offer a box of tiles that covers 35 square feet or a larger box that covers 60 square feet. Using the same pricing per square foot, you can easily enter the size of the box and the calculator will display the total price per box